# web based business intelligence tool using dc.js or olap for web application dashboard

Tags: mysql, web-applications, olap, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a Mysql database. I want to perform multidimensional analyse on this database and build web-based dashboard. 
I got little confused between using classic OLAP server like mondrian or SSAS or using dc.js =( d3 + crossfilter) which it provide very nice visualizations
can dc.js be considered as olap server and replace it? is there a way to combine both olap server and dc.js ?
the final objective is to build web application for browse the data in multidimensional way.

thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dc.js and OLAP are not comparable.

dc.js takes care of the visualisation, but you need to provide the data (as json or csv), so it still needs something to extract/aggregate the data you need to visualise.

What you use to generate that data is specific to your case, a thin layer on the top of a database might be enough, or may be not and it would work better if you have a more complete datawarehouse (OLAP).

In any case, dc is great if you know what dimensions and graphs you want in your dashboard and can code it, but if you want to have something your users can use to build their own dashboard and queries, other solutions (eg metabase) are probably more adapted.

Comment: thanks for your anwser. I still confused. I know that dc.js and olap are not comparable. my final objective is to perform multidimensional analysis on my data. If i convert my data to json or csv, can dc.js that includes crossfilter replace classic olap. or should i use both? I heard said that crossfilter is like olap client

Comment: Both could work, it really depends on the specifics of your data, it size, how often you plan to have new dashboard, your users...